# Problems with UTF-8 accent Characters in JQuery form submission using Internet Explorer

Tags: forms, utf-8, jquery

I am using JQuery to submit a form with $.ajax() and then get the params in a php page to store them in a Database.
My Pages are UTF8 encoded.

Everything works well when I use Firefox. However, with Internet Explorer, when the data has accent characters in it, it discards these completely.

I am using : `$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"});`

and also specify `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",` in my $.ajax() call.

Anyone able to help me with this one ?

Many thanks !

---

As requested :

```
$.ajax({

type: "GET",
url: "processing/addcontact.php",
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",

scriptCharset: "utf-8",

data: dataString,
    success: function() {

        reset_new_contact_form();
        $('#dialog-newcontact').dialog('close');

        }

});
```

and

the form is sent to a simple `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["formval1"])` in a SQL query.

Comment: What happens on client side? Can you show the full code you are using?

Comment: How can I see what happens on client side with IE ? On Firefox I have Firebug, and I can see that everything is ok.

Comment: What exactly is "dataString"?

Comment: It's a parameters string consisting of param1=value1&param2=value2...
I am doing a GET with it.
It works correctly in Firefox.

Comment: I know, but how do you *make* that string? Are you using "encodeURIComponent" to encode the parameter names and values? That will not be done for you automatically - you have to do it yourself (unless you're using a jQuery facility to serialize a form).

Comment: No, you're right, it should be encoded... that's what I'm missing I think. 
Should I use encodeURIComponent on every parameter or on the whole string ? I mean, will it break my &'s if I apply it to the whole string ?
Many thanks for your help

Comment: Pointy, you found the problem !

Please post as answer, so that I can give you the points.

encodeURIComponent() on every parameter value did the trick !

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, Pointy's answer was the best.

use : encodeURIComponent

Comment: A good answer should provide some basic details as to apply to a wider audience. A short snippet of code at the very least and a little context would really help.

Use encodeURIcomponent... where? how? why?